Edd Event Listeners to the Cube View Faces In Forge Viewer
How can I add event listeners to the faces of the view cube in the forge viewer ?
I can of course add an event listener to the entire cube but that's not what I need. I want to capture the click event at the faces only.
Thanks

Unfortunately, there is no event triggered when clicking view cube faces. May I know why you want this and what the benefits will be？
